# Camunda integration with camunda-bpm-camel community edition drops exchange property set between routes

Tags: apache-camel, camunda

Integrating Camunda with Apache Camel Community Edition and facing issue where in Exchange property set in Service Task One in the above image is dropped when accessed in Service Task Two. Both the Service Tasks are calling `${camel.sendTo('direct:one')}` and `${camel.sendTo('direct:two')}` Apparently it seems the exchange properties are retained only when routed between direct endpoints, but in this case the properties are dropped.

## Route1 and Route2

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:one")
                .bean(SomeClass.class, "someMethod")
                .to("http4://localhost:8002/one")
                .bean(SomeClass.class, "someMethod")
    }

@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:two")
                .bean(SomeClass.class, "someMethod")
                .to("http4://localhost:8002/two")
                .bean(SomeClass.class, "someMethod")
    }
```

[Here in the image one can see the camel sendTo endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL4Rk.png)

Answer (score 1):

Though you are sending to direct endpoints, I think new exchanges will be created as each route is connected with a separate service task. You can confirm this by logging the exchangeId for each of the routes. In each route, just add a `.log("${exchangeId}")`. Since properties are a part of the exchange and not the message, those are lost. You can try setting your data in the headers and check.